# how to fix this EventArgs c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build my own Simple Calculator.

I have this method with 10 references (from 0-10)

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        tb.Text += b.ToString();
    }`
```

Everything is working but the text sent to the TextBox come with extra things that I don't need.

[image]

I just want to show the number that I clicked on the calculator. I want to hide the "System.windows.forms.button, Text:" and show only the 7(in this case)

Comment: `ToString()` usually returns *debugging info* (*class name* by default). Use `Text` property instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Button.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `Button` instead of `ToString()`

```
 tb.Text += b.Text;
```

Comment: also specify to remove "Text" which will come by default when you drag and drop an asp textbox :)

Answer (score 1):

As Adil points out just use the Text property.

A further improvement can be made to your code base by instead of using the generated Event handler, create a single reusable event handler

instead of

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    tb.Text += b.Text;
}
private void button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    tb.Text += b.Text;
}
private void button_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
```

You could instead just have the single event handler. Remember to update your pointers on your buttons to point to this event handler.

```
private void numericButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    tb.Text += b.Text;
}`
```